# 'Scrollbar' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, tkinter

so I tried inserting a scrollbar into my Window with this code:

```
scrollbar= Scrollbar(root)#root is my window
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
for element in list:
    scrollbar.insert(END, element)
scrollbar.pack(side="left")
```

but the attribute I'm trying to use somehow doesn't work...
I got this error:

`AttributeError: 'Scrollbar' object has no attribute 'insert'`

Could someone please help me I don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks actually, 'Scrollbar' object actually **does not** have attribute 'insert' , I think you were trying to use 'Listbox' object which also is used to make a scrollbar (to make it functional) , because it has 'insert' attribute (I mean 'Listbox')

So this is a sample code for a scrollbar and how to use it! Even make it functional and useable! :)

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("150x200")

w = Label(root, text ='My Scrollbar',
        font = "50")

w.pack()

scroll_bar = Scrollbar(root)

scroll_bar.pack( side = RIGHT,
                fill = Y )

mylist = Listbox(root,
                yscrollcommand = scroll_bar.set )

for line in range(1, 26):
    mylist.insert(END, "Item Num#" + str(line))

mylist.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH )

scroll_bar.config( command = mylist.yview )

root.mainloop()
```

For more check this! [Python-Tkinter Scrollbar - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-scrollbar/)

Tell me if it works!

Comment: You can edit the Python Code so it is suitable for you! No problem at all! Or I can help you editing it too.

Comment: OMG! It was that simple!? I just had to change from scrollbar to list box! Thanks That helped so much!

Comment: No problem! Just always think and focus to any mistake! Maybe a small mistake, gets a error which makes you stuck!